# SQLite logic error

Tags: android, sqlite

I get the following error when tring to perform a query via QSB. I have created database with required columns for QSB.

```
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.native_fill_window(Native Method)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:75)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:288)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:269)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:171)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:248)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at com.simple.search.DatabaseHelper.query(DatabaseHelper.java:65)
11-30 20:12:49.805: E/DatabaseUtils(2116):  at com.simple.search.DatabaseHelper.getRecordMatches(DatabaseHelper.java:76)
```

DatabaseHelper.query

```
private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String[] columns) {
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDb, columns,
            selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return cursor;
}
public Cursor getRecordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}

public Cursor getRecord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
    String selection = "rowid = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}
```

**edit : added getrecordmatches, added getrecord**

Comment: can you give the values of the parameters (selection, the selectionArgs, and columns) which gives you that exception

Comment: thanks for the code, but can you give the exact values for Selection, SelectionArgs and columns that gives that error. I don't really anything wrong with the code that's why i'm asking .... maybe seeing the values of those parameters will be more helpful

Comment: @pdiddy Sorry for late reply. Internet problem. `selection : suggest_text_1 MATCH ?, selectionArgs[0] :*, columns[] : { BaseColumns._ID, SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a completely diffrent cursor. It's primitive but it works.

```
private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String[] columns) {
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this),
            ("selection : " + selection + ", selectionArgs[0] :"
                    + selectionArgs[0] + ", columns :" + columns));
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = selectionArgs[0];
    Cursor cursor = mDb
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT " + columns[0] +", "+ columns[1] + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + columns[1] + " LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { "%" + query  + "%" });
     if (cursor == null) {
     return null;
     } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     cursor.close();
     return null;
     }
     return cursor;

}
```